# Can't access BIOS - (NEC Express 5800 140hd)

Tags: hardware

When i try to enter the BIOS pushing F2 when asked (*"Push F2 to enter..."*) i can see *"Entering the BIOS..."* for 3 seconds on the screen and then my server continue to start normaly.

(notice: i can hear an alarm)

Battery issue ?

Can I try to flash with the latest (old) FW ?

Thanks for your help an suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can/have you reset the CMOS?? Maybe there is a stuck setting. I think if you flash the bios you may take everything with you (settings) to the new version.